# Where can I find Telda's Ring or Ring of the Selonan?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I found these on the wiki [Ring of the Selonan](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Ring_of_the_Selonan) & [Telda's Ring](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Telda%27s_Ring). How do I get them in game?

Comment: They are both gainable (dropping from enemies) somewhere before arriving at Dryford crossing, not below 5th level of Endless Paths. Which leaves only about 66% of the game to check, which will have to wait until next playthrough.

Answer (score 1):

The locations of these 2 items are in the Wiki entries you've linked.

[Ring of the Selonan](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Ring_of_the_Selonan):

> **Acquisition**
>
> Corpse in hidden cave accessible with Rope and Grappling Hook, SW of Pearlwood Bluff

[Telda's Ring](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Telda%27s_Ring):

> **Acquisition**
>
> Sold by Lora in Lora's Mystical Goods, Copperlane, Defiance Bay

Answer (score 0):

Telda's Ring is on the Merchant Lora in the Marketplace in Copperlane, Defiance Bay 8250cp